# Basemap does not show plotted data (if plotted at all)

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib-basemap

I've just recently started using basemap, and i've encountered a problem.

When i run :

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import netCDF4 as nc
import glob
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import warnings #note that I did not include all of my code, so some imports may be unnecessary. 

%matplotlib inline
datapath = "/somedirectory/www.ncei.noaa.gov/data/avhrr-land-leaf-area-index-and-fapar/access/2001" #I've downloaded the data from here as well, I've averaged over every month.
datafiles = glob.glob(datapath+"/"+"avg_LAI_fAPAR*.nc")
data = [None]*len(datafiles)
month = [None]*len(datafiles)
lats = [None] * len(datafiles)
lons = [None] * len(datafiles)
fAPAR =[None] * len(datafiles)
LAI =[None] * len(datafiles)

for number, file in enumerate(datafiles):
    month[number] = file[-4:-2]
    data[number] = nc.Dataset(file,format = 'NETCDF4')
    lats[number] = data[number]["latitude"]
    lons[number] = data[number]["longitude"]
    fAPAR[number] = data[number]["FAPAR"]
    LAI[number] = data[number]["LAI"]


m = Basemap(width=5000000,height=3500000,
            resolution='l',\
            lat_ts=40)
for k in range(1): #only do one loop, it takes a long time to run on my machine. Idea is that is should be able to loop through all months in 2001
    print(k)
    plt.figure()#figsize=(20,10))
    lon, lat = np.meshgrid(lons[k], lats[k])
    xi, yi = m(lon,lat)
    cs = m.pcolor(xi,yi,np.squeeze(LAI[k][0])) #note that the first dimension [k] comes from the for-loop, the second [0] is the temporal part of the LAI (avereged out in a bash script). 

    m.drawcoastlines()
    m.drawcountries()

    cbar = m.colorbar(cs, location='bottom', pad="10%")
    plt.title('LAI on {}'.format(month[k]))`
```

The plot comes out empty, so nothing plotted (only white space). The data is masked, but also if I unmasked the data (i.e. replace the masked data by a `nan`), the plot did not show anything. The `np.nanmean(LAI[0])` is about `1`, but the regular mean is about `-90`, as the fill value is `-100`.
The data seems to work with NCview in linux.

I work on python `3.6`, with the latest packages installed. Does anyone know where the problem might be?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried and got good result working with only 1 file?

Comment: yes, it resulted in the same map. However, the scale of the color bar does change with the input files.

Comment: Could you please make this a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? With the question in this form it is quite unlikely for you to get help.

Comment: @ThomasKühn Do you mean that the files are unavailable? Files can be downloaded from [link](www.ncei.noaa.gov/data/avhrr-land-leaf-area-index-and-fapar/access/2001). The bash file I ran over the files:

Comment: I do not seem to be able to add newlines in `code`, but anyway:
`for f in ./*.nc`
`do` 
`newname=$f` 
`newname=$( echo $f | sed -E 's/_c[0-9]{14}//' )`
`newnewname=$( echo $newname | sed -E 's/-[0-9]{2}//' )`
`mv $f $newnewname`
`done`

`for number in 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12`
`do`
`echo $number`
`ncecat AVHRR-Land_v004_AVH15C1_NOAA_$year$number*.nc` `LAI_fAPAR_$year_$number.nc`
`done`

`for number in 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12 `
`do`
`echo $number`
`ncra LAI_fAPAR_$year_$number.nc avg_LAI_fAPAR_$year_$number.nc`
`done`

Comment: I don't want to download all the files and I doubt that anybody else does. My point is that if there is something wrong with your code, you can reproduce the problem without the files (for instance some fake data with nans). If something is wrong with the files, you'll probably have to look at these and pick *one* file that produces the problem.